# Polymer paper-dialog exit animation not working

Tags: polymer, paper-dialog

I just started learning Polymer and I'm trying to put entry and exit animation on a paper dialog. It seems like the entry animation works perfectly, but the exit animation is not. I'm do a workaround by manually coding a jQuery, but I would like to use the built in capability of paper dialog.

Thanks.

```
        <paper-dialog id="dialog" entry-animation="slide-from-top-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" class="dialogstyle" no-cancel-on-outside-click no-cancel-on-esc-key>
        <div class="buttons">
            <paper-button id="closebutton" dialog-dismiss autofocus><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></paper-button>
        </div>

        <strong>content here</strong>

    </paper-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exit animation should work as long as you remember to include the `fade-out-animation.html`.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/web-animations.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/animations/slide-from-top-animation.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/animations/fade-out-animation.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-dialog entry-animation="slide-from-top-animation"
                exit-animation="fade-out-animation" opened>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <div>Dialog body</div>
  </paper-dialog>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RRpaNO?editors=1000)